# Padrino app not aware of its own root path

Tags: thinking-sphinx, padrino

I have a Padrino app which doesn't seem to be aware of its own root path. The app works fine, but when I try to require a file I wrote and put into the `models` folder, it says it cannot find it. The file is required from within another file in the models folder: `DvdActor.rb`. I can use any of these paths and it won't find it:

```
/app/models/file.rb
file.rb
models/file.rb
app/models/fie.rb
...
```

It will only find it if I use:

```
"#{Padrino.root}/app/models/file.rb"
```

Furthermore, the `Thnking Sphinx` gem will also have problems writing its configuration file or indexing (if I hardcode the path to the config file).

And when I have Padrino generate a Model, it will create a new `model` folder in the root folder insted of in the app folder itself.

I could recreate my app from scratch and copy the files over but I already have Heroku and git setup, etc. and don't want to recreate all this (sometimes simply copying the files over doesn't work properly).

Is there a way to reset this?

Comment: where you require those files?

Comment: I require the files inside a model file. But even the Thinking Sphinx gem cannot get the `@app_root` variable. It displays `@app_root=nil`